# Bottom Border not showing up (tables)

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <table style="width:70%; margin:0 auto;">
        <tr style="margin:0; border-bottom: 2px solid black; padding:0;">
          <td colspan="2"><img src="pre_header.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin:0; padding:0;">
          <td style="width:35%; margin-left:0;"><img style="width: 100%" src="logo.jpg" alt=""></td>
          <td style="width:35%; clear:right; margin-right: 0;"><h1 style="margin-left: 2rem">Monday 16<sup>th</sup> december 2019 <br> Volume 5</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 4px solid #000;">
          <th style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><h1>SEBI Updates</h1></th>
        </tr>
```

Why is the bottom border not showing up here?[picture of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdNO4.png)

Comment: Did you use bootstrap4 CDN? @flameskull2001

Comment: You should add the border-bottom property to the 'th' tag. Please don't use table in table, this will generate html validation errors.

Comment: @MeghnaBhuptani No I didn't I am creating an html Email so am only using CSS and HTML

Comment: @LeventeGabos wdym I did not get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to the table style border-collapse:collapse;

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <table style="width:70%; margin:0 auto;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr style="margin:0; border-bottom: 2px solid black; padding:0;">
          <td colspan="2"><img src="pre_header.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin:0; padding:0;">
          <td style="width:35%; margin-left:0;"><img style="width: 100%" src="logo.jpg" alt=""></td>
          <td style="width:35%; clear:right; margin-right: 0;"><h1 style="margin-left: 2rem">Monday 16<sup>th</sup> december 2019 <br> Volume 5</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 4px solid #000;">
          <th style="text-align: center;" colspan="2"><h1>SEBI Updates</h1></th>
        </tr></table></table>
```